# Is it possible to have servlet in sap web IDE project?

Tags: servlets, sapui5, sap-fiori

Is it possible to have servlet in sap web IDE project?. If yes, How can i do it?. Please provide an example or some references. I would like to have a Email servlet in my project. So that instead of opening client's email, I can send email directly with a button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot have servlet in Web IDE project. using WebIDE you can create only HTML5 projects (JS,CSS,HTML) . 
If you want to integrate servlet you can do it by creating a Java app on HCP and then create destination in HCP which points to your java servlet endpoint and from Web IDE project you can execute an ajax request in order to get the data to the client.

Here are some references:

[Developing and deploying a basic Java application on SAP HANA Cloud Platform](http://go.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hcp-java-basic-app.html)

[Connecting Remote Systems](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?5c3debce758a470e8342161457fd6f70.html)

[a blog that i wrote on how to consume 3-party services in Web IDE](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2016/03/22/webide-how-to-consume-3-party-services-in-ui5-app)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your description & reference !! It really helped.